# model.update is not working in node.js mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking to add a new Document to my collection. I am using blog.update() for the same.

In this code Blog is a collection name and Blog.update does not add the blog post to my database

```
  app.post("/compose",function(req,res){
    const blogTitle = req.body.postTitle ;
    const blogPost =req.body.postBody ;
    Blog.update({},{ $push: { title: blogTitle, post: blogPost }, function(error,foundList){
              if (error) { console.log(error); }
              else { console.log("sucesfully added the item"); console.log(foundList); }
              }
          });
        });
```

Comment: What do you want to update or you wanted to save something new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action you're trying to implement is not Blog.update, which is meant to change the information contained in an existing entry of your collection; but Blog.create:

```
app.post("/compose",function(req,res){
    const blogTitle = req.body.postTitle ;
    const blogPost =req.body.postBody ;
    Blog.create({ title: blogTitle, post: blogPost }, function(error,foundList){
              if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                }
              else {
                  console.log("sucesfully added the item");
                  console.log(foundList);
                }
              }
        );
```

I would strongly suggest reading the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create) in order to clarify these concepts.